# IBM Bluemix Container shuts down as soon as it is created

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud

I am trying to create a container on IBM Bluemix. I followed their guides and did these:

1. Created an image on localhost
2. Pushed the image to Bluemix
3. Created a volume on Bluemix
4. Created a container on Bluemix with the volume mounted on it.

I used this kind of command for creating a container:

```
 bx ic run -m 512 --name container1--volume ibmodmdcvol:/opt/ibmsoftware registry.eu-gb.bluemix.net/bluemix_images/ibmodmdc:v1 v1 bash -c "tail -f /dev/null"
```

The container gets created but it is in a shutdown state as soon as it is created. I am not able to upload anything on the container.

Comment: If you `bx ic inspect` the container in question, or check `bx ic logs` on that same container, do either show a bit more of what's happening there? Shutdown state usually means that it started, but then exited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please run `bx ic inspect` or `bx ic logs`. Without knowing slight more details, it is not possible to provide you any clue to correctly proceed to fix.

Please note that, [same question asked on dWanswers](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/400788/container-shutsdown-as-soon-as-it-is-created/) and admin Bill Wentworth on dW noted this URL of StackOverflow for cross reference.